# Regex named capture group with dynamic name

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a string of key-value pairs, separated by commas, but for simplicity, suppose I have only a single key-value pair: `foo=bar`.

Is there a way how to create a named group, where the name will be determined by whatever comes before the `=` sign and value whatever comes after? Regular capture group with name `foo` looks like this:

```
.*?=(?<foo>.*)
```

I have tried capturing the key with another group and then replacing the `<foo>` by reference to that group, but in named groups, only alphanumeric characters are allowed between the `<` and `>`:

```
(?P<key>.*?)=(?<(?P=key)>.*)
```

Comment: Group names are static, you cannot set group names during regex execution. You do not usually need that, you may create a hash/dictionary (or whatever it is called in your language) after you grab all the matches. What is your programming language?

Comment: I am not using any programming language - the purpose I need this for is to parse log files in FluentD, and these log files contain contextual information in form of a map. I can use static names for the keys, but I wanted it to be able to adapt to changes (e.g. adding a new key or different order of the pairs) in my log files.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is 4 years old and has no answers, Google has suggested it at the top to me, so I'll post my own solution. The original poster had no special programming language in mind, this is how it can be done in JavaScript:

```js
const path = '/one/:two/three/:four/five/six/:seven';
const params = [...path.matchAll(/:(\w+)/g)];
const paramNames = params.map(function paramName(param) {
  return param[1];
});
let regexPath = path;
for (const paramName of paramNames) {
  // /:foo/ ---> /(?<foo>\\w+)/
  regexPath = regexPath.replace(new RegExp(`:${paramName}`), `(?<${paramName}>\\w+)`);
}
console.log({ regexPath });
// prints: {regexPath: "/one/(?<two>\\w+)/three/(?<four>\\w+)/five/six/(?<seven>\\w+)"}
// Now it's ready to be passed to a RegExp constructor (Notice how backslashes have been escaped, this is needed when keeping regex as a string).
```